# Calculus showing with mods

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I got this problem from my Calculus II teacher, I have no idea how to approach it...

> Show that if $a,b,c$, and $d$ are integers such that $a\equiv b\pmod m$ and $c\equiv d\pmod m$, then $a+c\equiv b+d\pmod m$ and $ac\equiv bd\pmod m$.

If anyone can help, thanks!

Comment: Rewrite $b$ and $d$ as $a + mk_1$ and $c + mk_2$ by the definition of modular equivalence. Then calculate $b+d$ and $bd$.

Comment: So, would I literally do: $b+d=a+mk_1+c+mk_2$ and $bd=2ac+cmk_1+amk_2$?

Comment: Just $ac$ on the second one, but yes. Can you use the definition of $x \equiv y \mod m$ to show the end result?

Comment: I mean $ac$ in place of $2ac$. Yeah there are other terms.

Comment: Ok, so: $ac+amk_2+cmk_1+mk_1mk_2$?

Answer (score 0):

If $a \equiv b\ \  \text{mod}\  m$ and $c \equiv d\ \  \text{mod}\  m$ it follows* that $m |(a-b)$ and $m|(c-d)$ then there exist $r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$a-b = m\ r_1\ \  \text{and}\ \  c-d = m\ r_2$$ What can you say about $(a-b) + (c-d)$?

You take from here.

Same idea goes for $ac \equiv bd\ \  \text{mod}\  m$.

(*) Show that $a \equiv b\ \  \text{mod}\ \ m \Leftrightarrow m|(a-b)$ (It folllows directly from two facts : (i) Euclidean Division (ii) if $x|(y+z)$ and $x|y$ then $x|z$).

Comment: I can say that it is equal to $m(r1+r2)$?

Comment: That's right!  You got it.

Comment: Wait, so the final answer is $m(r1+r2)$?

Comment: You want to get that $m|(a-b)+(c-d)$. If you let $r_3=r_1+r_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ then you already have the result, because $(a-b) + (c-d)$ is a multiple of $m$.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as to what that means.

Comment: It means that $(a-b) + (c-d)\equiv 0\ \  \text{mod}\ \ m \Rightarrow a + c\equiv b+d\ \  \text{mod}\ \ m $.